# how to rewrite this nested query in a better way?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have this sql which finds the total number of (distinct) students who have taken course sections taught by the instructor with ID 10101.

```
            select count (distinct ID)
            from takes
            where (course_id, sec_id, semester, year) in 
            (select course_id, sec_id, semester, year
            from teaches
            where teaches.ID= 10101);
```

What is another or best way to rewrite it.

Your help will be apprecaited.

Comment: What's the problem with this query? it looks fine to me: A semi-join (IN/EXISTS) is both an efficient way to access data and a good way to convey meaning.

Comment: I want to rewrite it another way which is efficient to avoid sub query.

Comment: If this is a performance question, you should provide the explain plan, the actual query time and the expected query time as well as any index, all table structures and data volume.

Comment: There is no better way to get that result without using SEMI-JOIN (IN/EXISTS). It's more efficient and easier to read/understand than all the alternatives. If your strange principle to determinate a better query is "to not use nested queries" then Madhivanan suggested the right answer to you, but it's not always true using conventional terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use ANSI Join?

```
select 
    count (distinct t1.ID) 
from 
    takes as t1
    inner join teaches as t2 on 
        t1.course_id=t2.course_id and
    t1.sec_id=t2.sec_id and
    t1.semester=t2.semester and
    t1.year=t2.year 
where 
    t2.ID= 10101
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select count (distinct ta.id)
from takes ta
where EXISTS
(select 1 from teaches te
where te.ID=10101
and te.course_id=ta.course_id
and te.sec_id=ta.sec_id
and te.semester=ta.semester 
and te.year=ta.year)
```

Use EXISTS since this returns a BOOLEAN true/false to the outer query as soon as it has been evaluated.